# Simple algebra math in Java showing wrong answer

Tags: java

I am using this code in BlueJ for my school project, but this is returning wrong answer. I have tried everything, but each time I enter this value - A = 1, B = 2 and C = 3, it is showing 1 as answer which is incorrect.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class ABCD
{
    public static void ABCTest() {
        double a, b, c;
        Scanner inputNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of A, B and c");
        
        a = inputNumber.nextInt();
        b = inputNumber.nextInt();
        c = inputNumber.nextInt();
        
        double aSquare = a*a;
        double bSquare = b*b;
        double cSquare = c*c;
        
        double ax = (1/aSquare);
        double bx = (1/bSquare);
        double cx = (1/cSquare);
        
        double x = (1/a*a) + (2/b*b) + (3/c*c);
        System.out.println("Value of x is: " + x);
        
        System.out.println("Value of A square is: " + aSquare);
        System.out.println("Value of B Square is: " + bSquare);
        System.out.println("Value of C square is: " + cSquare);
        
        System.out.println("Value of A divide is: " + ax);
        System.out.println("Value of B divide is: " + bx);
        System.out.println("Value of C divide is: " + cx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, I do not know which is incorrect, since 1 multiplied by 1 is 1

Comment: Works for me too - after changing `ABCTest()` to `main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 2):

Intellij Input/Output:

```
Enter the value of A, B and c
1
2
3
Value of x is: 6.0
Value of A square is: 1.0
Value of B Square is: 4.0
Value of C square is: 9.0
Value of A divide is: 1.0
Value of B divide is: 0.25
Value of C divide is: 0.1111111111111111
```

Code is fine.

**UPDATE**

You probably expected the value of `x` to be equal to sum of these

```
Value of A divide is: 1.0
Value of B divide is: 0.25
Value of C divide is: 0.1111111111111111
```

But you are wrong. Because in statement:

```
double x = (1/a*a) + (2/b*b) + (3/c*c);
```

If a = 1, then (1/1*1) means first it divides 1 with 1 which is equal to 1, then multiplies 1 with 1, which is equal to 1.

The same with b and c, because you assign values of 2 and 3 to them.

In the end 1+2+3=6

Comment: in this line (1/a*a) + (2/b*b) + (3/c*c) must change code and add () for each power function

Comment: @SoheilBabadi I was just writing that, while you commented it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is operation priority that determines the order of calculations.
I changed the code and it will work correctly:

```
double a, b, c;
    Scanner inputNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value of A, B and c");

    a = inputNumber.nextInt();
    b = inputNumber.nextInt();
    c = inputNumber.nextInt();

    double aSquare = a*a;
    double bSquare = b*b;
    double cSquare = c*c;

    double ax = (1/aSquare);
    double bx = (1/bSquare);
    double cx = (1/cSquare);

    double x = (1/aSquare) + (2/bSquare) + (3/cSquare);
    System.out.println("Value of x is: " + x);

    System.out.println("Value of A square is: " + aSquare);
    System.out.println("Value of B Square is: " + bSquare);
    System.out.println("Value of C square is: " + cSquare);
```

Value of x is: 1.8333333333333333

Comment: you can write double x = (1/(a*a)) + (2/(b*b)) + (3/(c*c)); because of order of calculation in java